Localhost frequently rejects the connection when starting the ASP.NET Core Web API project
For the past few days, I have been trying to resolve the issue of localhost connection rejections in my RESTful API project, which occur either randomly or consistently when launching the API over HTTPS.
I have been working to resolve the issue, and I believe I have identified that the problem lies in the configuration of the builder and app in Program.cs. This realization came after several debugging sessions where the API successfully connected each time because of "more time". Therefore, I tried using app.RunAsync instead of the default synchronous method, and the API now has a higher chance of establishing a successful connection.
I've also tried resetting localhost certificates, but it didn't help. Moreover, I have a very similar smaller project where I have never encountered localhost rejection. I can't understand where I'm making a mistake and what I'm doing wrong. I've tried changing the database provider, switching http/https ports, and adjusting connection configurations, but still no positive results. What could be the cause?
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, logger) =>
{
     logger.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
});   
  
builder.Services.AddScoped<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ZlecajGoDb");
        
services.AddDbContext<ZlecajGoContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
.EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<User>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ZlecajGoContext>();
        
services.AddScoped<IZlecajGoSeeder, ZlecajGoSeeder>();
services.AddScoped<IOfferRepository, OfferRepository>();

var applicationAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
        
services.AddAutoMapper(applicationAssembly);
services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(applicationAssembly));
services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(applicationAssembly)
.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var seeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IZlecajGoSeeder>();
await seeder.SeedAsync();

app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGroup("/api/identity")
    .WithTags("Identity")
    .MapIdentityApi<User>();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

await app.RunAsync();


Here is link to repository.

What do you mean by "localhost connection rejections", are you failing to start the project or to connect the database in your api request? Please describe your issue with more details and more precise description. I downloaded and tested your code, I can immediately and successfully start the project and connect the database and query the offers whether run or runasync. What is the log information in your project, your log level is set at warning level, you could change to get more log details. You could also select another machine to test if it is a reproducible issue.

@FengzhiZhou When I try to run the project, either I connect to localhost without any problems (which is rare in my case), or I get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error and have to restart the project frequently until it eventually starts and runs correctly. When I perform a sample update-database in Entity Framework Core, I've never had any issues, so the database is fine. I also checked on another machine and didn't have such problems. I really don't know what is going on in this project, really strange behaviour.

This could be caused by various reasons, let's check this step by step. First are you using VPN? If yes, turn off to check if it will work. Second, raise your log level to level and catch the messages.
